# cakePHP Shopping cart tutorial

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

Is there any online tutorial available for building a shopping cart in cakePHP 1.3 or cakePHP 2.0? There are cakePHP shopping cart solutions available like [vamcart](http://vamcart.com/) but they don't have well documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check here :

[7 Best Shopping Cart Plugins For CakePhp](http://www.enfew.com/7-best-shopping-cart-plugins-for-cakephp/)

use **cakecart** it's well documented

Comment: That is cake-cart.I have used. BTW for coding when you will use anyone of these you will become familiar with code.

Comment: thanks Teez, I am going to study it, I tried to vote up your answer, but sorry I don't have enough reputation to do so. thanks anyway

Comment: What is the best approach to change this into a plugin? Is it  just changing the `extents AppController` to say `extends CakeCartAppController` throughout the whole application? As well as the models? Thanks!

Comment: I could not find a 2.0 cart plugin neither matched any of the ones I looked at my standards so I've started my own https://github.com/burzum/Cart

Answer (score 1):

A simple PHP Shopping Cart built with CakePHP PHP framework.

https://github.com/andraskende/cakephp-shopping-cart

Comment: The shopping cart looks good, thanks! It mentions that the app is incomplete, just wanted to ask what's not done?